# nginx reverse proxy: host not allowed error

Tags: proxy, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy. One server is a play server. When I try to proxy the server, I receive a 400 Host Not Allowed error.

flow

```
                                         ----------(services1)
                                         |----(services2)
client ----(https)---> nginx ---(http)---|-------(services3)
                                         |----(services4)
                                         ---------(services5)
```

(i.e. the client talks to nginx via ssl and then nginx acts as a reverse proxy to whatever backend is needed over http).

I'm trying to test this out with a dummy scala play backend.

I have an `nginx.conf` that looks like:

```
http {
    ...

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    upstream play-backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    include sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Now, I have a `default.conf` (inside sites-enabled) that redirect http traffic over ssl:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    list [::]:80 default_server;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    ...
}
```

Then, inside my `default-ssl.conf` (inside sites-enabled), I have my reverse proxy logic:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ... certificate and other stuff ...

    location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://play-backend;
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully divert traffic over ssl, but I'm not sure why I can't proxy to any of my backend services. I have a feeling I've organized everything wrong and it's somehow trying to use https to communicate with the play server.

I can confirm the play server is working by directly hitting `localhost:9000/`

EDIT: Specifically, the problem is that nginx makes a request to the backend service *from* myexampledomain.com rather than from localhost. I'm not sure how to send the request *from* localhost *to* the backend service and then return it to the client from the domain over ssl.

Comment: It seems changing `proxy_set_header Host localhost` will work, but I'm not sure if that's safe. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic comment which I'll delete once you've seen this: please come here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39776961#39776961 regarding your recent deleted question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to setup the Allowed Host Filter on your application.conf. You should use the can use "." to allow any Host, or you could use "myexampledomain.com" .

```
   play.filters.hosts {
     # Allow requests to myexampledomain.com.
     allowed = ["myexampledomain.com"]
   }
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AllowedHostsFilter